# Wordpress get_posts if keyword exists in title, content or tag

Tags: wordpress, search, tags, keyword

I am using get_posts to get a list of posts that match a search keyword, the problem is that I the `get_posts`'s `s` [parameter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Search_Parameter) does not search tags by default and using `tag_slug__in` will not work if the keyword is found in the title and not in a tag.

The conditions of my search would be:

1. Return post if keyword exists in Title
2. Return post if keyword exists in Content
3. Return post if keyword is a tag associated with the post.

Any ideas would be fantastic. I tried the "Search Everything" plugin, but that only seems to work on WordPress' default Search Feature.

Code below is a simplified version of what I have attempted, not this does not satisfy all 3 criteria.

```
<?php

/* Set global query parameters */
$image_args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => (isset($_GET['show_all']) && $_GET['show_all'] == 'true')? 100000 : 20,
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => array('image/jpeg', 'image/png'),
    'meta_key' => 'language',
    'meta_value' => "(^".$languages."$|\"".$languages."\"\;)",
    'meta_compare' => 'REGEXP',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'media_category',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => array($gallery_filter, $hotel->term_id),
            'operator' => 'AND',
        ),
    ),
);

/* If page numbert given, add offet */
if(!empty($page_no))
    $images_args['offset'] = 20*((int)$page_no-1);


/* If search term submitted, add it to the s parameter */
if(isset($_GET['search'])){
    $image_args['tag_slug__in' = explode(" ", $_GET['search']);
    $image_args['s'] = urldecode($_GET['search_term']);
}
```

Comment: I know about the WP_Query parameters and have detailed my attempts. I have a lot of conditional logic in my query and pasting the code here will take it out of context. I will try my best to simplify it.

Comment: @rnevius, I've added the code I have attempted or at least a simplified version (which may contain syntax errors due to quickness of producing an example).

Comment: it would be cool if `WP_Query` would support a general `field_query` argument that supported nested field queries. It would be a long term project to build such a plugin, but I guess the starting point could be a proposal like [this one](https://gist.github.com/birgire/ebf79ab6b12258a0e489). @PieterGoosen

Comment: @birgire that would definitely be a huge bonus in core, or even just a plugin. Talking long term, I've been busy for months with a huge paging plugin which supports referrers, all the classes are done, I just need to write the final functions, but to sit down and write them... Getting lazy, and I'm going back into playing guitar again, so....

Comment: @birgire also speaking about nesting stuff, something like your idea would be quite cool for searching. Lets be honest, the build in search function is a quite crappy ;-). This is really an interesting question which I haven't sat down and think about properly.

Comment: yes I agree, the native search could be more flexible. I think such a nested field query support might solve lot's of problem here on SO or WPSE. Let's see what happens with this ...  (looking forward to your plugin release - have fun with the guitar ;-) @PieterGoosen

Comment: @rnevius, how would you do it?

Comment: I ended up doing 5 queries: 1: A `get_posts` using regular keyword search using the `s` parameter. 2: Getting all tags for the post_type. 3: Iterating through tags to find tag IDs which represent tags that have keywords in their name. 4: I then did another` get_posts` query getting posts where `tag__in` parameter is set to the tag IDs I found in step 3. 5: I merged the two arrays and filtered them to make an array of unique posts.

Comment: I don't know if it does what you'd want it to do, but there's a new search plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-search-live/) that uses the REST API (http://wp-api.org/). It's still beta, seems promising.

Comment: I was able to sort of solve this using `$wpdb` and some queries to get the IDs from matched posts, but, by the comments, it seems you did the same thing

Comment: Hi, not sure if this is exactly what you need but check out this article, it helped me with a similar problem: [http://www.cssigniter.com/ignite/programmatically-get-related-wordpress-posts-easily/#comment-156265] if you scroll down to "generalizing the code" something like this might help: `array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
            'fields'   => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'tag2' )
        ),`

Answer (score 1):

you can use your own query . below is an example

```
$querystr="
    SELECT *
        FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->term_relationships, $wpdb->term_taxonomy, $wpdb->terms
            WHERE ($wpdb->terms.name = '$s'
            OR $wpdb->posts.post_content LIKE '%$s%'
        OR $wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '%$s%')
        AND $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id
        AND $wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
        AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = $wpdb->terms.term_id
        ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC
";

$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT_K);

foreach ($pageposts as $post): setup_postdata($post);
    echo the_title() . '<br /><br />';
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used `wpdb` query to fetch the result. Join the posts and taxonomy table and then get the distinct result by `$search_title`. Hope this will work. :)

```
global $wpdb;
$querystr= "SELECT DISTINCT $wpdb->posts.* FROM $wpdb->posts
                LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships
                    ON ( $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id )
                LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy
                    ON ( $wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id )
                LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms
                    ON ( $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = $wpdb->terms.term_id ) 

                WHERE ( $wpdb->terms.name LIKE '%$search_title%'
                    OR $wpdb->posts.post_content LIKE '%$search_title%'
                    OR $wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '%$search_title%' )
                    AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
                    AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'product' 
                    ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_title ASC";

$query_object = $wpdb->get_results($querystr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Post Clauses](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_clauses) filters Wordpress offers. It allows you to plug in MySQL Statements directly to the WP query.